# PowerBi reports and SharePoint permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerbi

I'm looking at creating a Power Bi report / Dashboard which gathers information from numerous SharePoint sites.
I will be using a user(system) account with Power Bi licence. This system user will have read access to the sites and will be the user used to create the Power Bi reports.

When a standard user (with a power Bi licence) accesses the report, will they require permissions to the underlying SharePoint sites or only the Power Bi report?
I'm planning to test this to see for myself once the test accounts are set up but thought I'd ask in case there are some gothca's which i might miss.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your standard users need to have access to your PBI report only. This is done in PBI Online by sharing your report with user, users or user groups. Sharing the report should automatically grant access to report's dataset as well. However, I would recommend to check that explicitly.

Regards,
Zilvinas